# How to save an image filename with Date & time in C++?

Tags: c++, image, datetime, stereo-3d

I'm using a code to save images from a camera, but I need to save the filename with the current date and time the image is taken. How can I do this? I have tried many different codes from the internet but I always get many errors and programming is not my strong side. Any advice or help will be appreciated. This is the code: https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-save-depth/blob/master/src/main.cpp

Comment: You will need to extract the metadata from the image. This contains information about camera settings and when the picture was taken. There are numerous libraries that. Especially if the image is a jpeg one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
    #include <time.h>
```

for time. To get the current time :

```
    time_t current_time = clock();
```

To get the current date, you can use :

```
    struct tm *localtime(const time_t *time);
```

Which returns a struct for the local time that looks like this :

```
    struct tm {
      int tm_sec;   // seconds of minutes from 0 to 61
      int tm_min;   // minutes of hour from 0 to 59
      int tm_hour;  // hours of day from 0 to 24
      int tm_mday;  // day of month from 1 to 31
      int tm_mon;   // month of year from 0 to 11
      int tm_year;  // year since 1900
      int tm_wday;  // days since sunday
      int tm_yday;  // days since January 1st
      int tm_isdst; // hours of daylight savings time
    }
```